# Can't run Forge for Minecraft 1.8

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been trying to download Forge for Minecraft 1.8 to get Toggle Sneak/Sprint.

I get it into my downloads:

[image: image of downloads]

But when I open it or try to run it, this happens:

[image: image of popup]

And when I save it, then open that one, the same screen pops up.

**Isn't it supposed to come up with the regular Forge downloader screen?**

Comment: Where are you downloading it from?

Comment: This question is off-topic both as tech support for modded minecraft and as being about how to download jar files in internet explorer, which can happen in non-game contexts too, as opposed to being about gaming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a computer-related question not specific to video games. It is better suited at [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Your file extension associations are all messed up, it's trying to open a file intended to be used with your Java executable using Internet Explorer.

what you should do is follow the guidelines set by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511063/how-to-run-jar-file-by-double-click-on-windows-7-64

> - Start "Control Panel"
> - Click "Default Programs"
> - Click "Associate a file type or protocol with a specific program"
> - Double click .jar
> - Browse C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe*
> - Click the button Open
> - Click the button OK

- NOTE: depending on how you installed Java and what version you installed, it might be located somewhere else. The above path is for a default installation of java 7. It appears like you installed Java 8, which will have a different path. If you want to be absolutely sure what path to use, you should do the following:
- right-click the Windows button and click on "Command prompt".
- enter the following text: `Java -verbose`
- A bunch of text will scroll down. this is normal. at the end of this text is something like `[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown$Lock from C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\lib\rt.jar]`. Java will in this case be installed in `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101`.

This is all assuming you already installed java, obviously. If you haven't installed java yet, do so first. Forge requires Java to run.